# how to make every group in expandable list view single selectable?

Tags: android, layout

Hi have activity with expandable list view. In that I have to select single child from every group. so that i created a child with single_selection list_item.xml file and at run time I set single selection property to true.

this is my output.

[image]

selection of first item works fine until I select second item. when I select an item from group 2, selected item from group 1 gets unselected. give me any idea to achieve.

For single selection

```
  xp_list.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Adapter class
    public class DegreeAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
    private List<String> group;
    private Map<String, List<String>> array = new HashMap<>();

    DegreeAdapter(List<String> group, Map<String, List<String>> array) {
        this.group = group;
        this.array = array;
        //Logger.Log(TAG, "CONS===>" + array.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        //Logger.Log(TAG, "CONS===>" + array);
        return group.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return array.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return group.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return array.get(getGroup(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.preference_header, parent, false);
        }
        String title = getGroup(groupPosition);
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(title);
        xp_list.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            //Logger.Log("inside contain", "inside view null=");
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, parent,
                    false);
        }

        String singleObj = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (selectedIdList.contains(singleObj)) {
            Log.i("inside contain", "id=" + singleObj);
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(false);
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView;
        titleView.setText(singleObj);
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        convertView.setTag(singleObj);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Try to Use Below code Snipet**/ 

implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener
in your activity class

your_expListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

Then override the onchildCount method of Expandable Listview Method

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
    /**Do you Selectable code over here**/
    return false;
}
```